# Movie Identification: 1980/1990's movie with flying creatures and a beautiful actress

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Key facts about the movie:

- Late 80's to mid 90's. I think I watched it about 20 years ago around
  1995 ±5 years.
- Horror. Not overly gory and a little bit sleazy. Most likely some kind of age restriction due to the content i.e. excessive nudity.
- Starts with a sequence with a young couple making out in a park late at night. The young guy cops a feel and then these flying creatures that look like bats come and kill them. (not sure if both die)
- The lead actress is a beautiful young woman with either brown/dark hair who ends up somehow in a house or being watched by an old guy who controls these monsters. I am not sure whether the old guy is a monster(vampire?) or not.
- There is a scene with a furnace (or something similar) which is located underneath the house.
- I am not sure whether they are vampire bats or just flying monster who eat people.
- Not big budget but reasonably well made. Possibly direct video.
- Lots of nudity involving the lead actress. Shower scene and sunbathing scene.

I have gone through the entire list of horror movies on IMDB for the 80's and 90's and still didn't find it, so it has to be pretty obscure. Thanks for any help, I never saw the end of the movie and I think about it every few years or so.

Comment: You shouldn't post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: sorry removed from other site. is this the best site for it? I noticed the other one doesn't seem to have as much activity.

Comment: actually, the other site was probably be the better fit :) Horror doesn't also imply science fiction.

Comment: This is a good site for story identification for anything fantasy, science fiction, or (supernatural) horror. Your question mentions monsters, so it fits well.

Comment: @JohnP, John O speaketh the truth.

Comment: @Pureferret - Ok, I'm agreeable. :)

Comment: Definitely multiple creatures, right?  Not a single creature a la Jeepers Creepers?

Comment: I can't remember exactly, it possibly could have been the old guy in bat/flying monster form. Updated the question with some more info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

["Not of This Earth"(1988)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_of_This_Earth_(1988_film))?

> Nadine Story (Traci Lords) is a nurse working in the office of Dr. Rochelle (Ace Mask). She encounters an unusual patient Mr. Johnson (Arthur Roberts), who is always dressed in black, wears dark sunglasses and demands a blood transfusion. After Dr. Rochelle tests Johnson's blood, he's surprised to discover the man's body isn't producing blood in the usual manner, and Johnson hires Nadine to work in his home and give him regular transfusions. With the help of her boyfriend Harry (Roger Lodge), she soon discovers that Johnson an emissary from the planet Davanna, who is looking for a ready supply of human blood his people need to survive.

It stars Traci Lords and is directed by Jim Wynorski and looks 'sleazy'. I think it does have a lot of nudity and it also has an alien who uses smaller, flying bloodsucking creatures and he has a furnace. There is also a scene of Traci Lords sunbathing by a pool. This was a remake of a 1957 film and there was also a 1995 version, but I think this is the one. Also should mention that I have only seen the 1957 version, so I'm guessing here.

The opening scene does have a couple making out (in their car) in a park at night when they're approached by a mysterious man. However, the guy dies after his neck is grabbed and the girl has her life-force sucked out of her before her blood is removed using a machine.

Comment: Also the older guy is a vampire from another planet and the young woman is his nurse. He does control the flying creatures.

Comment: There are no "flying creatures" in that move, though.

Comment: Thanks guys. It was the 1995 version for sure! I may of been mistaken about the flying creature as this is the movie i was after. There was something that floated around but it certainly wasn't batlike like i thought it was. I guess I have another movie to find as well :)

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty much sure you mean this one:

[Without warning (1980)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081764/)

Comment: Hmmm, took a look at the trailer for that one and I'm not sure it is it. The lead character (protaganist) was a brunette/black haired beautiful girl. Also the name doesn't sound that familar. Does this one start with a young couple making out? The flying monster does fit the bill though. I think it was more recent than 1980 as well.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the film Lifeforce with french actress Mathilda May, although the plot doesn't really fit your description.